# Youtube API v3 upload get Video Link

Tags: youtube

I am new to the Youtube API.
I am trying to use it to upload a file through my page on youtube.
Everything is working, and the File gets uploaded.

Now i want to display the link to the Video, so i can save it in the database. Its also enough if i can log it in the console and make an ajax call to save in the db.

The point is, i dont know how to get it.
I am using exactly the code form here:https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have it already, it's the video id in the response after you upload.

**https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource**

Then the url is like this - **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*id***